# SAP BO 4.2 SP07 inList clause in webi

Tags: business-objects, webi

Can i use another column in InList clause?

Example,
i have created a variable and below is the formula.

```
IF [query1.column1] inList ([query2.column2]) then SUM([query1.amountColumn])
Else 0
```

OR is it possible to put variable after **inList** in formula?

If not possible -- is there any other alternative to this?

Comment: What is the potential number of rows returned for **query2**? Can you predict that with any degree of certainty?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible approaches. I will to use the eFashion universe for both solutions.

**Solution #1**

Here are my 2 queries to begin...

[image]

[image]

Run your queries. Click on the columns you want to compare, [query1].[column1] and [query2].[column2] in your case; [Query 1].[Month] and [Query 2].[Month] for me. Right-click and merge them. They must be dimensions and of the same data type.

[image]

Now create a variable based on [Query 2].[Month Name] which you can filter on to eliminate the results from **Query 1** that do not match up to anything in **Query 2**.

[UV Month Name]=[Query 2].[Month Name]

The key here is you need to change the **Qualification** to "Detail" and set the **Associated Dimension** to what we just merged by clicking three dots to the right. Choose [Month Name] not from either query, but the merged dimension.

[image]

Now build out your table with whatever object you want from **Query 1** and add in the variable we just created.

[image]

Now add a filter on that variable to only show row where it is not null.

[image]

And you are done.

[image]

Pros

- Works when limiting query (query2) has a relatively large number of values (compare to Cons for Solution #2).

Cons

- More complicated to set up
- May run into universe or performance issues related to query being filtered (query1).

**Solution #2**

Building upon Solution #1, I duplicated **Query 1** and renamed it **Query 3**. Now you can choose "Results from another query" to get the [query1].[column1] InList ([query2].[column2]) logic you want.

[image]

If you take this approach then you don't need to do the merge, variable, and filter. The results of the query are filter before being returned by the report.

Pros

- Simple

Cons

- The number of values coming from your second query must be relatively small. It varies by database or maybe even your universe. I have found if it is over 1,000 values I get an error when I run the query that it is "too complex".